# If $\max\limits_{|z|=1/2}|f(z)| = |a_4|/2^4$, then $f(z) = a_4z^4$.

Tags: complex-analysis, alternative-proof

**Problem:** Suppose $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ when $|z|<1$. Show that if $|a_4|=2^4\max\limits_{|z|=1/2}|f(z)|$, then $f(z) = a_4z^4$.

I have a proof when $f$ has no zeros in $0<|z|<1$ but not in general. I also have a proof which uses Parseval's theorem. I would like to see a proof that uses only tools from a standard complex analysis course.

**Proof (assuming $f$ has no zeros in $0<|z|<1$)**

> Using the Cauchy's formula, we can get
> $$ |a_4| = \dfrac{|f^{(4)}(0)|}{4!} \le \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|w|=1/2}\dfrac{|f(w)|}{|w^5|}|dw| \le 2^4\max\limits_{|z|=1/2}|f(z)| = |a_4|. $$
> So all the inequalities above are actually equalities and in particular we get that for all $z$ with $|z|=1/2$ one has $|f(z)| = \max\limits_{|z|=1/2}|f(z)| = |a_4|/2^4$. So $f$ maps the circle of radius $1/2$ to another circle. If $f$ does not have zeros in $0<|z|<1/2$, then we can reflect $f$ about the circle $|z|=1/2$ to obtain an entire function by defining
> $$ \overline{f(z)} = \dfrac{(|a_4|/2^4)^2}{{f\left( \dfrac{1}{4\overline{z}} \right)}} \quad\text{for}\quad |z|\ge 1/2. $$
> The order of the pole of this entire function (say $k$) is same as the order of the zero of $f$ at the origin. Then the function
> $$ g(z) = \dfrac{f(z)}{z^k} $$
> has a removable singularity at the origin and no zeros in $0<|z|<1/2$. Hence we can similarly reflect $g$ to obtain an entire function which is bounded near $\infty$. Hence by Liouville's theorem $g$ is constant and we get
> $$ f(z)=cz^k \quad\text{for some constant }c.  $$
> If $k<4$, then $a_4=0$ and we get that $f$ vanish on $|z|=1/2$ (see the second sentence) and it is identically zero (by the identity theorem). Hence $f(z) = 0 = 0z^4$ is trivially true then. If $a_4\ne 0$, then we get that $k=4$ and $c=a_4$ and we are again done.

**Proof using Parseval's theorem**

> Note that
> \begin{equation}
>   \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f\left( e^{i\theta}/2 \right)|^2 d\theta \le \max_{|z|=1/2}|f(z)|^2 = \left( \dfrac{|a_4|}{2^4} \right)^2. 
>  \end{equation}
> Also note that the Fourier series of $f$ is
> $$ f\left( e^{i\theta}/2 \right)  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n \left( \dfrac{e^{i\theta}}{2} \right)^n  = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{a_n}{2^n}e^{in\theta}  $$
> and hence the Parseval's identity tells us
> \begin{equation}
>   \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f\left( e^{i\theta}/2 \right)|^2 d\theta = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac{|a_n|}{2^n}\right)^2.
>  \end{equation}
> Substituting the last equation in the first displayed formula gives us
> $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac{|a_n|}{2^n}\right)^2 \le \left( \dfrac{|a_4|}{2^4} \right)^2 $$
> and this tells us that $a_n$ must be zero for all $n$ other than $4$.

Comment: How about using the maximum modulus principle? Since $f(z)$ is expressed as a positive powers series it is analitic and convergent inside $|z|<1$. Then at the contour $|z|=\frac{1}{2}$ it haves to reach it's maximum there.

Comment: @ppmbb I do not see how the argument proceeds from there. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, we have the chain of inequalities
$$ |a_4| = \dfrac{|f^{(4)}(0)|}{4!} \le \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\{|w|=1/2\}}\dfrac{|f(w)|}{|w^5|}|dw| \le 2^4\max\limits_{|z|=1/2}|f(z)| = |a_4|, $$
and thus both inequalities are in fact equalities. The fact that the second inequality is an equality implies that $|f|$ is constant on the circle centered at $0$ of radius $1/2$. The first inequality being an equality gives, after parametrization $w=(1/2)e^{it}$, becomes

$$\left| \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{f((1/2)e^{it})}{((1/2)e^{it})^5} \, \frac{i}{2}e^{it} \, dt \right| = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{|f((1/2)e^{it})|}{(1/2)^5} \frac{1}{2} \, dt.$$

This implies that the integrand on the left must be a unimodular constant multiple of the integrand on the right, i.e.,
$$\frac{f((1/2)e^{it})}{((1/2)e^{it})^5} \, \frac{i}{2}e^{it} = \alpha \frac{|f((1/2)e^{it})|}{(1/2)^5} \frac{1}{2}$$
for all $t \in [0,2\pi]$, for some $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=1$. Recall that the right-hand side is constant, and we get
$$f(z)=Cz^4$$
for all $z$ with $|z|=1/2$, for some constant $C$. This remains valid for all $z$ with $|z|<1$, by the identity theorem. The constant $C$ must be $a_4$ by uniqueness of power series coefficients.

Comment: The first (in)equality tells us $\left| \int_{|w|=1/2}\dfrac{f(w)}{w^5} dw\right| = \int_{|w|=1/2}\dfrac{|f(w)|}{|w^5|}|dw|$. So the integral inside the absolute value in LHS is equal to RHS times a complex number of unit length. How does one arrive at your second displayed formula?

Comment: @iota It's easier to see after parametrization $w=(1/2)e^{i\theta}$. Try that see if it helps, I can add more details if not.

Comment: I am sorry but I am feel like I am missing something obvious here. Can you please add more details? Everything else in you answer makes perfect sense.

Comment: @iota I added more details.